# How to handle special characters like & and / in .htaccess rules?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file I have defined following rule,

```
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z]+) search.php?id=$1
```

The above rule works fine if I am browsing http://example.com/abcd
I need to use the symbols `& % - /` in the url like: http://example.com/ab&cd

What changes have to be made to the rule for this to work?

Comment: The actual URL is `http://example.com/ab&cd`? Seems odd.

Comment: I need the URL to work when its `/AT%26T` or even if its `/AT&T`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No idea how that rule is working for you. First, it loops. Second, there is no capture groups for `$2` and `$3`, but it doesn't matter because `$1` is always "search" anyways. I'm assuming you've pasted a partial snippet of a rule that you have that works.

The reason why `&`, `%`, or `/` isn't being matched is because your regex says:

```
[-0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

which means: *one or more letters, numbers, or a dash*. So no `&`, `%`, or `/`. So you can add those into the square brackets:

```
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+) search.php?id=$1&ff=$2&ffid=$3
```

However, keep in mind that the URI is **decoded** before any rules get applied. This means if the URI looks like:

```
/foo%28bar
```

You don't need to match against `%`, because the URI gets decoded into:

```
/foo(bar
```

and you need to match against `(`. A better option may to just match against every *except* dots:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+) search.php?id=$1&ff=$2&ffid=$3
```

or whatever you *don't* want in your match.

---

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ search.php?id=$1 [B]
```

The difference here is the `$` to bound the match to the end of the URI, and the `B` flag ensures the `&` gets encoded.

Comment: Sorry about the last two ID parameters in the rule, they are not used here. I tried both the rules you've mentioned above but, if the url is `/AT%26T` or `/AT&T` only the `AT` is received in the search.php file.

Comment: having same problem I have used the answer solution but it's not working here on my app, this is the idea the actual link is(http://m.host/web/sref.php?page=1&refone=1&reftow=%) ........which after using the .htaccess it will be like------(http://m.host/web/sref/1/1/%) but it's not working

Comment: @abas_rafiq Try posting it as a question, as you can't format anything in comments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280755/how-to-manage-search-result-with-pagination-on-htaccess-shortening

Comment: @jon lin , that's my question

Comment: I have problem, my url is `http://example.com/search/ZO$qP#U5` in url it works fine, but in php it shows only `ZO$qP`, so what I need to do? Is it PHP issue? or help me if anybody knows. I want `ZO$qP#U5` as a variable in php. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode `'ab&cd'` using [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode)
so that `&` gets turned into `%26`.

After this, in search.php you'll need to account for it and decode it, using [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Do the URL like this:

```
http://example.com/id/ff/ffid
```

and write your rule around that. Also, why do you need 3 ID parameters? Couldn't you just lookup the other 2 using the first one?

Comment: Sorry, the last 2 parameters were not needed here. I've removed them from the question.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)\/? search.php?id=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

### Do with your url

```
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/.]+)$ /searchpage.php?search_keywords=$1  [L]
```